# Identify SAML-enabled apps in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm trying to build some governance around SSO-enabled applications in my environment.
I have multiple apps which has SAML/OAuth/OIDC integration with Azure AD.
Is there a way to get the data from Azure AD about "Which protocol this app is using for SSO?"

The end goal here to identify all SSO enabled apps with protocols used for future migration.

So far, I've tried to look into AzureAD and Az Powershell modules, but haven't found a way to clearly determine that from the cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from MS Q&A platform: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/24259/identify-saml-enabled-apps-in-azure-ad.html

You can use the following PS snippet:

```
 $type = "SAML APP"
 Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {($_.Tags -contains "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryGalleryApplicationNonPrimaryV1") -or ($_.Tags -contains "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication")} | Select DisplayName, @{Name="AppType"; Expression={$type}}
```

Every Application be it an OAuth app or SAML app (both gallery and non-gallery apps) would have two objects created in AAD when their registration happens. One is called the Application Object and the other is the Service Principal object. Now I used the Service Principal object to prepare this snippet. When you dump the properties of a Service Principal Object using PS, you would find that every application has a certain number of Tags associated with it like:

OAuth apps would have a tag called "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"

Gallery SAML Apps would have a tag called "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryGalleryApplicationPrimaryV1"

Non-Gallery SAML Apps would have a tag called "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication"

Hence you can use the following Tags and find out what kind of app is it. Now the following Tag "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp" is common to all types of apps {categories as mentioned in the above list}, hence the snippet i shared above, by using that you can list all the SAML apps (both gallery and non-gallery) and rest of the apps would be your OAuth apps.